# In the excel/vba IDE, How can I quickly see the code for a function in my code and then come back?

Tags: vba, excel

It is such a chore to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> everytime and then try to remember in what module I keep that function !!

Worse is sometimes the excel sheet is focused and I end up overwriting some data with that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> !

Answer (score 2):

The answer is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to go back !

I just found this on some forum.

You double click on a function or subroutine (which is somewhere in your code) and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and blammo ! You get teleported to it, no need for the Project Explorer !!

Then you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and it takes you back to where you were before!

Such a time saver !

Comment: Not sure why is this downvoted. Yup it quite a time saver. :)

Comment: Hi, I used a lot of your answers in my code, thanks a lot, especially 13984229 to stop co-workers stealing my scripts ;)